# Have CMAKE delete old coverage data

Tags: cmake, gcov

I am using CMAKE to for building and testing. I have it running code coverage. However, when I change the test source, it needs to clear the coverage data for the file being tested, but not other files.

For example, I touch TEST_Outputs.c but not Outputs.c. This causes TEST_Outputs.exe to be built.
This causes add_custom_command to execute TEST_Outputs.exe. A new TEST_Outputs.c.gcda is created. However, since Outputs.c was not rebuild, Outputs.c.gcda is not changed and accumulates coverage data from both the old set of tests and the new set of tests. I want to clear Outputs.c.gcda but not say Inputs.c.gcda.

My build folder has the following tree where the offending gcda are located in the .CMakeFiles/TEST_Outputs.dir/--/src/Outputs folder.

```
└───CMakeFiles
    ├───Test_LogicIn_Init.dir
    │   ├───mocks
    │   └───__
    │       └───src
    │           └───LogicIn
    ├───TEST_Outputs.dir
    │   ├───mocks
    │   └───__
    │       └───src
    │           └───Outputs
    └───TEST_SysStatus.dir
        ├───mocks
        └───__
            └───src
                └───System
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe)

#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# These arguments to gcc.exe are required in order to generate code coverage data
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
add_definitions(${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS})

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmocka-bin/AddCmocka.cmake)

#Add list of tests and their flags

#TEST_LogicIn test
LIST(APPEND tests_names "Test_LogicIn_Init")
LIST(APPEND tests_filename "TEST_LogicIn.c")
LIST(APPEND tests_flags "-Wl,--wrap=x_in_init,--wrap=x_in_get_value")
LIST(APPEND tests_mocks "mocks/mock_LogicIn.c")
LIST(APPEND tests_srcdir "../src/LogicIn/Logicin.c")

#TEST_SysStatus test
LIST(APPEND tests_names "TEST_SysStatus")
LIST(APPEND tests_filename "TEST_SysStatus.c")
LIST(APPEND tests_flags "-Wl,--wrap=x_sys_get_ignition")
LIST(APPEND tests_mocks "mocks/mock_SysStatus.c")
LIST(APPEND tests_srcdir "../src/System/SysStatus.c")

#TEST_Outputs test
LIST(APPEND tests_names "TEST_Outputs")
LIST(APPEND tests_filename "TEST_Outputs.c")
LIST(APPEND tests_flags "-Wl,--wrap=x_out_init,--wrap=x_out_set_value,--wrap=x_out_relay_set")
LIST(APPEND tests_mocks "mocks/mock_Outputs.c")
LIST(APPEND tests_srcdir "../src/Outputs/Outputs.c")


# Declare all tests targets
LIST(LENGTH tests_names count)
MATH(EXPR count "${count} - 1")
FOREACH(i RANGE ${count})
    LIST(GET tests_names ${i} test_name)
    LIST(GET tests_filename ${i} test_filename)
    LIST(GET tests_flags ${i} test_flags)
    LIST(GET tests_mocks ${i} test_mocks)
    LIST(GET tests_srcdir ${i} test_srcdir)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(${test_name} ${test_filename} ${test_mocks} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${test_srcdir})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
        ${test_name}
        PRIVATE
        cmocka
        ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        gcov
    )
    set_target_properties(
        ${test_name}
        PROPERTIES
        LINK_FLAGS ${test_flags}
        )
    
    ADD_CMOCKA_TEST(${test_name} ${test_srcdir})
ENDFOREACH()
```

AddCmocka.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

add_library(cmocka SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

target_include_directories(cmocka INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

set_target_properties(cmocka 
                      PROPERTIES 
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmocka.dll"
                      IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libcmocka.dll.a"
                     )
      
file(COPY        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmocka.dll"
     DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    )
   
# Macro for adding and creating the test
MACRO(add_cmocka_test executable_name source)

add_test(NAME RunCTest${executable_name}
         COMMAND ${executable_name} 
         WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )

add_custom_command(TARGET ${executable_name}
    #I want to delete old src.c.gcda here
    COMMAND ${executable_name}
    )

ENDMACRO()
```

The way I see it I can,

1. Add SourceFile.c.gcda to the list of targets somehow so that it is rebuild when the test executable is build. How would I do this?
2. Use CMake to delete the old *.gcda file. How do I get a reference to the subdirectory?